std::numeric_limits::epsilon() for double-double arithmetic
I am designing some double-double and quad-double arithmetic libraries for C++11. Part of the code is based off of the QD and DDFUN library from https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbsoftware/.
struct Float64x2 {
    double hi;
    double lo;
};
struct Float64x4 {
    double val[4];
};

Dekker-float types have some properties that regular floating point types do not. For example, being able to represent FLT_MAX + FLT_DENORM_MIN exactly, which would normally require ~2048bits of precision to represent (2^1023 + 2^-1074). Float80x2 requiring ~32768bits due to the larger 15bit exponent (image).
I used some of the values from QD for std::numeric_limits as a starting point. Although I am not sure if they are the best values to use. How should std::numeric_limits::epsilon() be defined for Dekker-floats?
std::numeric_limits::epsilon()
epsilon() is the difference between 1.0 and the next representable number. For double, epsilon is 0x1.0p-52, but I am not sure what it should be for Dekker-float types.

Taking the definition of epsilon() literally, it should be either numeric_limits<double>::min() or numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min() for both Float64x2 and Float64x4. Since they can both represent 1.0 + FLT_MIN and 1.0 + FLT_DENORM_MIN exactly.
dd_real and qd_real from QD define it as 0x1.0p-104 and 0x1.0p-208 respectively; which is probably a more useful definition of epsilon(). This definition can be used to determine when to stop adding terms to an approximation (i.e. using a Taylor-series to approximate sin(x)).
DDFUN uses a slightly different definition for epsilon (From ddfune.f90 dderfr), which is ldexp(1.0, -numeric_limits<T>::digits). This gives a slightly smaller epsilon of 0x1.0p-53 for double, and a value of 0x1.0p-106 and 0x1.0p-212 for Float64x2 and Float64x4 respectively.

Which definition for epsilon() should I provide through std::numeric_limits for Float64x2 and Float64x4?

Additionally, what should std::numeric_limits::<Float64x4>epsilon() return? Should it return a double (which can represent the value of epsilon exactly), or should it return the same type (Float64x4)?

std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() was designed for fixed-precision floating-point types, not “double-double” formats, and defining it to be anything can give clients incorrect information about properties of the format. Leave it undefined. To report information about the format to clients, you should create new methods with new names.

@Vortex 2728182818 Re "dd_real ... from QD define it as 0x1.0p-104". I would have expected 0x1.0p-105: The effective number of bits in a double-double is 52 + 52 + 1, where the "bonus" bit is represented by the sign bit of the tail.

IMHO, a reasonable definition for a pseudo epsilon of double-double would be: The smallest step size with which one can step through IEEE-754 binary128 operands in [1,2) such that the conversion chain binary128 -> double-double -> binary128 recovers the original argument, for each argument in [1,2). The numeric value of that pseudo epsilon would be 0x1p-105.

@EricPostpischil I appreciate that you are far more of an expert in all issues of FP precision and related matters. However, isn't "epsilon" a constant for any given system. That is, it's the smallest number that can be added to 1.0 and give a result that is different from 1.0? (My definition may not be verbatim from the IEEE standard but I think it has the gist.)

... in fact (just as an example), MSVC defines std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() as an inline that just does return DBL_EPSILON; and DBL_EPSILON is defined as #define DBL_EPSILON      2.2204460492503131e-016.

@AdrianMole 2.220446e-016 is equal to 0x1.0p-52 or 2^-52. Its the same value, just in decimal form instead of hex-float.

@Vortex2728182818 Yes, I know that. I'm just saying that, for whatever FP system you implement, the epsilon value is a well-defined (or, rather, well specified) constant. So, just put that value in a #define (or, better, constexpr) statement in the library's header.

... if folks choose to misuse your epsilon value (as many do, for standard types), then that's their problem, not yours!

@AdrianMole: You can take a definition of “epsilon” and apply it to double-double and determine that it has a specific value, but of what use is that? The notion of this epsilon was created to characterize the precision of a format. That works for fixed-precision formats. It gives you the step size that holds throughout the binade from 1 to 2. And it holds a constant ratio over the binades; the step size or ULP for 2, 4, and 8 is 2, 4, or 8 times the “epsilon” for 1. It does not serve that purpose for double-double: …

… Using that definition, the epsilon for double-double would be 2^−1074. But that does not tell you about the precision of the double-double (that it uses two 53-bit chunks), nor can you step completely from 1 to 2 in units of 2^−1074 (the steps would be irregular as the exponent of the lower double increases), nor it is a constant ratio over the binades (the distance from each of 2, 4, and 8 to the next representable value is also 2^−1074, not 2, 4, or 8 times that). So, sure, you have a definition for “epsilon“, and that definition determines a numerical value, but what is it good for?…

… And, if you take any program written to use an ordinary C++ floating-point type T, and that program uses std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() to manage its work with the type, will that program work with the epsilon() you provide for the double-double type?

@Eric Fair comment(s). So, maybe the question should be more explicit in explaining the need for an 'epsilon' (and other 'constants') in a system that has variable precision (or representation?). If there is only one way of representing 1.0 in a system, then I will maintain that using the standard definition of what epsilon means remains valid.

@Vortex2728182818 epsilon candidate for Float64x2: (DBL_EPSILON * DBL_EPSILON * 2) yet give it a different name.

Float64x2 and Float64x4 are not floating-point formats (discussed below) and should not be treated as such.


dd_real and qd_real from QD define it as 0x1.0p-104 and 0x1.0p-208 respectively; which is probably a more useful definition of epsilon(). This definition can be used to determine when to stop adding terms to an approximation (i.e. using a Taylor-series to approximate sin(x)).


Being useful does not constitute a reason to give a number the same name used for a feature of a different kind of format. To inform clients about properties of your formats, simply define new names.


Taking the definition of epsilon() literally, it should be either numeric_limits<double>::min() or numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min() for both Float64x2 and Float64x4. Since they can both represent 1.0 + FLT_MIN and 1.0 + FLT_DENORM_MIN exactly.

…
Which definition for epsilon() should I provide through std::numeric_limits for Float64x2 and Float64x4?

Taking the definition of epsilon() literally, you should not define it at all. C++ 2020 draft N4849 17.3.5.1 [numeric.limits.members] specifies it as:

25 Machine epsilon: the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable.
26 Meaningful for all floating-point types.

This informs us that epsilon() is not meaningful for Float64x2 and Float64x4, since they are not floating-point types. They are numeric types, in that they can represent numbers, but they do not conform to a floating-point model. A floating-point format represents a number x with an integer M (or, equivalently, a fixed-point value) and an exponent e with:
        x = M•βe−p+1
with |M| < βp and specific values for integers β and p and bounds on e that are fixed characteristics of the format. This is from Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic by Muller et al. The C++ standard does not state the floating-point model explicitly but inherits it from the C standard, which states an equivalent model (using a fixed-point M instead of integer). The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic uses an equivalent model.
Float64x2 and Float64x4 do not conform to this model. There are no integers β and p and bounds on e such that the set of numbers representable in the model is the set of numbers representable in Float64x2, and similarly for Float64x4. “Floating-point” is not a synonym for real numbers or fractions or non-integer numeric formats in general. It is a term for a specific kind of mathematical model.
Representing a number by the unevaluated sum of two floating-point numbers is a different model and is not a floating-point format as it is commonly understood by practitioners of floating-point arithmetic or as stated in the C standard and inherited by C++.
Since Float64x2 and Float64x4 are not floating-point types, they are not arithmetic types as defined in the C++ standard. 6.8.1 [basic.fundamental] 12 says “Integral and floating-point types are collectively called arithmetic types.” 17.3.5 [numeric.limits] 4 says “Specializations shall be provided for each arithmetic type,…” This does not explicitly say that specializations shall not be provided for non-arithmetic types, but observe that paragraph 6 says “Non-arithmetic standard types, such as complex<T> (26.4.2), shall not have specializations.” That is about standard types, but it is consistent with our observations: Defining values for numeric_limits members that were not designed to describe types other than the integer and floating-point types is problematic.
Whatever you do here goes beyond the C++ standard. You could define numeric_limits members with new names to describe new properties or you could define some entirely new template to describe properties. Either of these could be designed reasonably without interfering with standard uses of the numeric_limits template. What I do not recommend is using the existing names where they are inapplicable, as that can cause inconsistencies with standard uses of the template.

"Taking the definition of epsilon() literally, you should not define it at all.": That's not really correct. [numeric.special] specifies "All members shall be provided for all specializations. [...] Any value that is not “meaningful” shall be set to 0 or false.".

@user17732522: In [numeric.limits], paragraph 4 (of draft N4849) says specializations shall be provided for each arithmetic type. [basic.fundamental] paragraph 12 says the integral and floating-ing-point types are the arithmetic types. As this answer notes, Float64x2 is not a floating-point type, so it is not an arithmetic type. So it should not have a specialization of std::numeric_limits at all. I will update the answer to note that. Using 0 or false is only for arithmetic types that do have a specialization but then for which a particular member is not meaningful.

No user-defined type can be an arithmetic type, but std::numeric_limits is clearly intended to be extended by the user. I think "Specializations shall be provided for each arithmetic type," is supposed to be a requirement imposed on the implementation. But a user generally is allowed to add specialization for user-defined types as long as the specialization satisfies the original requirements. See [namespace.std]/2. I don't see a requirement that all specializations of std::numeric_limits need to be for arithmetic types. Still, it may not make sense to specialize for the asker's type.

While it is non-normative, the comments and footnotes throughout the specification of std::numeric_limits refer to ISO/IEC 10967-1:2012 indicating that the template is supposed to model the concepts specified therein. According to ISO/IEC 10967-1:2012 the asker's type is also not a floating point type or any other supported kind of type, so I think that is another good indicator that std::numeric_limits should not be specialized for this kind of type.

“Floating-point” is not a synonym for real numbers or fractions. I agree emphatically, and this point deserves repeating, for I fear that alternate notions are in wide circulation.  For all too many uncritical thinkers, it's pretty clear that "floating point" means "number that has a fractional part."  We've seen questioners talk about "floating point" when they are clearly thinking about (or even using) fixed point. (Related point: "significant digits" does not mean "digits past the decimal".)

Although epsilon is often defined as "precision near 1.0", that is not really a useful definition.  When a programmer actually uses epsilon in a program, it's to make some prediction or perform some evaluation about the way the program is performing.  And for that, we should use a more precise definition, and also honor a corollary which, if not formally part of the definition, is so important that it really does need to be honored.
Definition: Epsilon is the precision over the range [B0, B1], where B is the base of the floating-point format.  (For binary, B is 2 and a range like this is called a "binade"; while for decimal, B is 10 and a range is called a "decade".)
Corollary: For any other binade or decade [Bn, Bn+1], the precision is exactly n × epsilon.
Another observation: saying "precision near 1.0" is something like 50% misleading, for it's really "precision just above 1.0".  Just below 1.0, we're in the previous binade/decade, and the precision is actually much better, by a factor of B.
Corollary to the corollary: for any number X, the precision near X is approximately X × epsilon.  (But this approximation will be off by up to a factor of B.  And this leads to another definition, of the term "wobble".)
But the bottom line for this question, which is what the other comments and answer(s) are getting at, is that for a double-double format, the reason it's hard to come up with a single value for epsilon is that there isn't one, or at least, not one that works as expected with all of the definition(s) and corollaries I've described here.
